# Angularfire2- Cannot cast Observable<CustomType> to CustomType

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I cannot cast `Observable<CustomType>` to just `CustomType` like this:

```
custObject: CustomType;

ngOnInit() {
    this.custObject = this.customDocument.valeueChanges() as CustomTpe;
}
```

I receive an error like this:

> Observable cannot be converted to 'CustomType'. Property 'typeid' is missing in type 'Observable'.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to do this:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.customDocument.valeueChanges().subscribe(res => this.custObject = res);
}
```

A [little about observables](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables.html). I think you should read some documentation first.